# Can you change Pending (Incomplete Transaction) to Pending (Pay Later)?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, pending

Is it possible to change pending transactions from incomplete to pay later?
Without editing db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using api explorer you can do it or exporting the record and re importing it with status as pending and pay later as 1 or yes.